# Error using PHPStorm's SASS File Watcher

Tags: ruby, sass, phpstorm

I'm getting the following error whenever PHPStorm attempts to convert my SASS file to CSS using the file watchers:

```
/Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/sass --no-cache --update style.sass:style.css
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem sass (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
  from /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/sass:22
  from /Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

When I run the command in the terminal, everything works as expected:

```
/Users/Ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/sass --no-cache --update style.sass:style.css
```

Output:

```
overwrite style.css
```

I'm confused as to why it's complaining about Ruby 1.8 version missing SASS as I've edited my settings in PHPStorm to use Ruby 2.0 (via RVM). Here are my project settings:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Your Terminal has [different environment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891). If you run PhpStorm like this, it should work: `open -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/`. Or you can specify the same environment directly in the File Watcher settings (most likely `PATH` matters).

Comment: Using open -a fixed the issue! Where in the settings can I edit the PATH? I haven't been able to locate it.

Comment: See **Environment Variables** on your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks again! You should post your answer below so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have different `PATH` environment in Terminal and in PhpStorm, it's [Mac OS specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891).

Workarounds:

- Run the IDE from Terminal: `open -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/`
- Edit **Environment Variables** directly in the File Watcher configuration.

Comment: specifically you'll want to head to your prompt and `$ echo $PATH` copy that output, then head to PhpStorm's File Watcher config and click the `…` button by Environment Variables. On the next screen you'll see an empty list; click the `+` button and name your variable "PATH" (no "$") then paste what you just echo'd into the value field

Comment: @MarkFox Thank you! That worked for PhpStorm 2018.1 on Linux Mint 18.3