# PhpStorm Command Line Tools using OSX Version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpstorm

I have installed PHP 5.4 via macports opt/local/bin and configured my bash profile to use this version. However when I try to run the php command line tools in an IDE PHPStorm in this case, the IDE defaults to the OSX version ie 5.3. I have tried setting the interpreter in the IDE to 5.4 yet this has no effect. I guess that the IDE ignores all settings in the bash profile so is there something else I need to do to force the IDE not to use the OSX installed version of PHP.

Thank in advance for any help..

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18209348/104891) will help.