# Find the location of the SASS executable. (using rbenv)

Tags: rubygems, sass, webstorm, rbenv

I have a working SASS installation. I can run these commands in terminal and get this output:

```
sass -v
Sass 3.2.9 (Media Mark)

rbenv versions
  system
* 1.9.3-p392 (set by /Users/Eric/.rbenv/version)
  2.0.0-p0
```

I need to locate the exectuable so that I can provide it to the Webstorm IDE as a file watcher. http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/. I have set this up in other environments (windows, osx without rbenv) before, but can't figure out how to do it here.

If I run `whereis sass`, I get no output.

How do I find this executable and specify it for Webstorm?

Digging into rbenv, I see it here:
`/Users/Eric/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/bin/sass`
Specifying this path to webstorm does work. Is it appropriate/stable to reference this location directly, or is there a better way that doesn't depend on version numbers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193043/error-using-phpstorms-sass-file-watcher/18209348#18209348 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working answer for me:

```
/Users/Eric/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.9/bin/sass
```

It's not the best because I have to update the location when I upgrade SASS, but it's functional. Hope this helps someone else.

If someone knows of a symlink to the executable that is maintained through upgrades by rbenv or ruby, please share.

Answer (score 2):

Use `which sass` instead of `whereis`. It should be in `~/.rbenv/bin` location for you.