# content_shell in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

How can I get content_shell to work in the IntelliJ run command on Mountain Lion. Whenever I press run I get:

```
content_shell: command not found
```

So far I've edited my .bash_profile to add the alias content_shell that points to the "Content Shell.app" in my Dart directory. Opening IntelliJ from the terminal did not prove successful either.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18209348/104891) is related and should help.

Comment: Trying to create a file watcher for .sh files:I am unable to add .sh as a file type.

Comment: The point was not about file watcher, but about environment variables on Mac.

Comment: In my .bashrc/.bash_profile I have - alias content_shell="/Applications/dart/chromium/Content\ Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/Content\ Shell". But when I try open -a "IntelliJ IDEA 12" it now knows the PATH but I am not getting access to the content_shell alias.

Comment: It will not help, IDEA doesn't see anything you set in `.bash_profile`. Run it from terminal or set it in the run configuration environment.

Comment: run configuration environment - can launch.conf be used to avoid having to set each time?

Comment: `open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/` in Terminal and see if it helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36329/discussion-between-basheps-and-crazycoder)